# wpf ResourceDictionary source from binding

Tags: c#, wpf

in my app.xaml i have so many style to load this is that list

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/dark.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Orange.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/Button.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/CheckBox.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/Controls.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/ContextMenu.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/ScrollBar.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/ScrollViewer.xaml"/>
......
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

now i need change tow firs source url in run-time maybe to value from Properties.Settings.Default
i dont know what can i do 
i search about this but nothing can't find to Understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newsource1= new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/resources/xxxx.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var newsource2= new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/resources/yyyyy.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(Appl‌​ication.Current.Reso‌​urces.MergedDictiona‌​ries[0]);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(Appl‌​ication.Current.Reso‌​urces.MergedDictiona‌​ries[1]);

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = newsource1});
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = newsource2});
```

Since there is no functionality available to edit resource dictionary runtime. Possible solution to achieve what you expect is to remove and add resource dictionary runtime.

Sincerely,

Thiyagu Rajendran

**Please mark the replies as answers if they helps.